# Error when trying to connect to oracle data source

Tags: tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

**Tableau version:** 2021.2.8
**Oracle version:** Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bi

We have a tableau report built on oracle database. The data connection built using custom sql using multiple joins.
We are getting below error when trying to run the report. This issue occurs intermittently.
If we run the custom sql directly on the database, it just runs fine. Also other data connection built on the same database running without any issue.
Appreciate your suggestions or guidance on this issue. Thanks in advance.

**Error:**
No more data to read from socket
Unable to connect to the Oracle server ‘xxxxxxx’. Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.

**Error: (Tableau Desktop)**
An error occurred while communicating with Tableau Server
The connection to the data source might have been lost.
Error Code:BDBEAD43
Error: Unable to connect to this Tableau Server data source.
An error occurred while communicating with the Oracle data source 'xxxxxxxxx(local copy)' The connection to the data source might have been lost.
No more data to read from socket
Unable to connect to the Oracle server ‘xxxxxxxx’. Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
DataServiceFailure
There was an error with the data source "xxxxxxxxx". Verify that the data source is configured correctly.

Comment: Try using Tableau 2022.4 , recently many data connectors have been updated

Comment: Had the same problem just trying to connect from my Mac, I used the lates thin client from oracle and add it to the ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers, and everything worked flawlessly…